# Save property to NSUserDefaults when changed by user SWIFT

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to do this in Swift: 
I need an object that will have some properties. When the object is initialized for the first time all the properties will have some default values. If the user at any point changes a property this will be stored in NSUserDefaults and in the future when the object is instantiated again the properties default value will not be the hardcoded one but the one from NSUserDefaults.

So far I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to get a value that does not exist from NSUserDefaults. The property that sets the new value in defaults needs to be a computed property? What is the best way to check if a value exists in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Does `if let` syntax work? Haven't tried it on UD yet. `if let value = userDefaults["key"] { myObject.value = value }`

Comment: show the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Use registerUserDefaults to initialize the default values. This default value will only be used when there is no value for that property.

Comment: Any alternatives to initializing the defaults? How to check their existence if they are not initialized. The problem seems to be swift force unwrapping a fetched value .